# How is it possible that I get electric shocks from so many things?

Tags: electricity

This probably isn't the typical stack exchange question, but I still hope someone can explain this to me :)

A read in the title I get a lot of electric shocks, here are some examples

- If I get in or out a car and touch the metal chassis (I think this is quite common)
- If I press the button of the elevator, even when I wear gloves (I don't get this I mean gloves aren't great conductors :') )
- When I touch the rubber part you rest your arms on on an escalator (Again rubber?)
- When I plug in something in an electrical output (like my mobile phone charger), these shocks really hurt bad
- When I touch a person

And many more things

I guess most of it is just static current, but I don't get how I can get shocked while there aren't any conductors, nor why it happens so extremely often to me, like 5-10 times a day, and not to a friend.

This isn't such a serious question but any explanation would be great :)

Comment: It depends on the kind of clothing one usually wears, the kind of shoes one has. But escalator bands are the same for everyone, those do get charged, almost like Vandegraaf machines. And the friction between car seats and clothes also separates charges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things that build (+) charges include *but are not limited to* dry skin, dry hair, leather, glass, nylon, wool, many animal furs, and silk.

Things that build (-) charges include *but also are not limited to* silicon, PVC, rubber, scotch tape, shrink wrap, saran wrap, styrofoam, polyester, and conductive metals.

If you rub (+) items on (-) items, a charge will build. The shock is from a built up (+) charge on your skin (and/or clothes and hair) dissipating rapidly over a small area of skin, such as your fingertip. The name of the game in avoiding shocks is to avoid building up a (+) charge. This can be done by frequently discharging yourself. You can do this by staying slightly wet or carrying coins that you touch before touching the things that usually shock you. A good moisturizing lotion, conditioner for your hair, and a humidifier for your home will all help you to stay wet enough to avoid being shocked. You don't need to be damp. You just don't want to be very dry.

Comment: Notice that many of the items on the (-) list will often cling annoyingly to your skin. This is because your skin is positively (+) charged.